# Get top number of rows anyway

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is like select top 5 rows from sql, if it contains only 2 rows then by default it shows some text say 'no data' in remaining 3 rows. Same for all conditions.

**For i.e. Select top 5 rows, but it contains only 3 rows then query will return**

Row1
Row2
Row3
No Data
No Data

Comment: yeah, i am thinking. i can do it by using c# coding but I want it using sql query only.

Comment: Use C# coding for return message

Comment: What is the structure of the row? In which column should it say "No Data"?

Comment: it contains 3 columns. after using top and remaining total rows, it should display any default value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
select top 5 Col 
from(
    select 0 srt, Col from YourTable

    union all

    select 1 srt, 'No Data' Col union all
    select 1 srt, 'No Data' Col union all
    select 1 srt, 'No Data' Col union all
    select 1 srt, 'No Data' Col union all
    select 1 srt, 'No Data' Col
)x
order by srt
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be much more dynamic

```
    declare @t TABLE (id int,TerminalID varchar(15))
    declare @top int
        set @top = 5

    declare @c int --Holds Total
        set @c = 0
    while (@c < @top) begin
        insert into @t (id, TerminalID) values (@c, 'No Data')
        set @c = @c + 1
    end

    select top 5 * from
    (
    select top 5 TerminalID from AccessLog-- [where colo0 = ???]
    union all
    select TerminalID from @t
    ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* assuming the column width is 8 characters and datatype is varchar */    
DECLARE @NoDataTable AS TABLE(column1 VARCHAR(8)) 

DECLARE @i AS INT
SET @i = 0

WHILE(@i<5)
BEGIN

    insert into @NoDataTable (column1)
    values('No Data');

    set @i = @i+1
end

select top 5 * 
from
(
     select column1  from TestTable
     union all 
     select column1 from @NoDataTable
) as T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT YourColumn FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 5 NULL FROM YourTable
)           
SELECT TOP 5 COALESCE(YourColumn, 'No Data')
FROM cte
```